# Redux state design with Redux-observable

Tags: redux, state, redux-observable

My current project is quite similar to a Facebook newsfeed, which shows a list of posts. Inside each post, there's a 'load comments' button which allows loading the comments of each posts. After user clicks the 'load comments', I want to show a loading icon inside the post. Since I'm using Redux-observable, I put all  of the api calls in epics. Traditionally, my api call flows like this: ACTION_START -> update redux state (isFetching: true) -> ACTION_FINISH -> update redux state (isFetching: false). You see this 'isFetching' design is not suitable for that list of posts in my feed since each post must listen to a different 'isFetching'.

My initial thought is to move 'isFetching', let's call it isFetchingComments, to inside the `<Post />` component (it is now a react component state, not redux state) but since I'm using epics for api calls, are there any ways to update a React component state based on a redux action?

My second solution is to still store 'isFetchingComments' in redux (can be manipulated with epics) but as an array of postIds like isFetchingComments: [post1, post2]. And each time a post is fetching comments, update redux accordingly.

But I'm feeling like the second solution though might work, is not the cleanest one to apply here.
Please tell me how should I design the state here. thanks

Comment: Please show us the code for what you have tried and then tell us what the problem is with your solution. It sounds like you have answered your own question though.

Comment: Did you find a solution for Your problem? Did You pick one of your solutions? I'm having the same dilemma atm as you had back then